# How to constrain text of video player controls to container

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a video player with controls that scale when the window is enlarged/shrunk. How can I get the "time-total", "time-played" and "timeline" to conform to the "video-controls" div as the play/pause, mute and fullscreen controls do?

Currently using the following jQuery to control the buttons:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
// resize on dom ready
resizePlayer();

// add window resize binding
$(window).resize(resizePlayer);
});

function resizePlayer() {
    var newWidth = $('.timeline').outerHeight() * 0.25;
    $('.play, .mute, .fullscreen').width(newWidth);
}
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/zq2vzkk5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I found that applying the same functionality, you set a percentage to the font and calculate with the following:

```
var containerSize = $('.video-controls').width();
    var textPercentage = 0.17391304347826086956521739130435; /* 40/230 */
    var textRatio = containerSize * textPercentage;
    var textEms = textRatio / 244;

$('.time-played, .timeline, .time-total').css('fontSize', textEms+"em");
```